# Is it Possible to Dismiss MFMailComposeViewController Without User Interaction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am able to successfully dismiss my `MFMailComposeViewController` in the `didFinishWithResult` delegate method.  However, I have a scenario where I would like to dismiss the composer without user interaction, like selecting cancel or sending the mail.

I have looked in apple docs and was unable to find anything entirely useful. I have tried calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated` but that only seems to be working when I am inside the  `didFinishWithResult` delegate method.  Is there anyway to force that delegate method or dismiss the composer alternatively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are presenting your mail controller from a `UIViewController`, you may dismiss it programmatically by calling the `UIViewController` method:

`dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`

See this apple reference: [dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW103)

You did mention:

> I have tried calling dismissViewControllerAnimated but that only seems
>   to be working when I am inside the didFinishWithResult delegate method

What you are experiencing may be indicative of a different problem as I was able to successfully do this outside of the `mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:` delegate method.

**Example:**

```
-(void)showMail
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    //Set the message, subject, etc...

    //Display
    [someViewController presentViewController:mailController animated:YES completion:nil];

    //As a proof of concept, close programmatically after a couple of seconds...
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissMailController) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
}

-(void)dismissMailController
{
    [someViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Well now I feel silly. This is what I tried but the method that it was in was not being called. Just over thought it I suppose. Thanks!